# how to install kubuntu in empty notebook

Tags: kubuntu

I am a none IT or computer gig. 
I'm having a notebook previously installed with microsoft windows - virtually.
This microsoft window OS was totaly erased cleaned from HDD and totaly removed from the notebook. Now no OS.
I have downloaded kubuntu/xubuntu OS to a CD.

When open the notebook. The BIOS page setup appears.
When try to install this new OS, this massage apears on note book screen. 
'partition not reconise' or "partition not found"

How to reformat and install Kubuntu through external CD drive hooked to my notebook without any OS.
I can go to BIOS page to setup.

Please advicd

Comment: Are you able to change the boot order in the BIOS to boot from the external CD first? From there you will normally be able to install regardless of what's on the hard drive.

Comment: A CD is too small for today's Ubuntu. You will need a DVD or an empty USB drive. Once you setup the USB drive as a live USB, you will be able to try Ubuntu without installing on that notebook. If that goes well, click on the install icon on the Live running Ubuntu.

Comment: _user68186_ is right, the LTS (most stable) version of Kubuntu is 1.8GB, 3 times the capacity of a CD. https://userbase.kde.org/Kubuntu/Installation and https://linuxhint.com/install_kubuntu_1804/ provide step-by-step instructions to follow to download and install to a 2GB or larger USB flash drive..